# Limit collection - .first doesn't work with CompositeViews

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I want to show the first 100 entries, or entries between 101 and 200 in the collection.

If I create a Marionette CompositeView and specify

```
someRegion.show new MyCompositeView(collection: myCollection.first(100))
```

I get an error. Passing only `myCollection` works. What are the correct syntaxes for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used Marionette, but...

`Collection.first(n)` returns an array of models, not a collection object.  If the view is expecting that property to be a Collection, but you're passing an array, this is your issue.

You could take the results from the .first(n) and pass it into a new collection:

```
someRegion.show new MyCompositeView({collection: new Backbone.Collection(myCollection.first(100))})
```